# PHP object wont echo a property

Tags: php, oop, object

I am trying to learn PHP OOP on codeacademy and I think I am going insane.
I have compared my code with the example code in every single way and it just wont work!
Please help me understand what is going wrong here, when i try to echo the age property from the object $student, made from the class Person

```
  <?php
    class Person {
        public $isAlive = true;
        public $firstname;
        public $lastname;
        public $age;
        public function __contruct($firstname, $lastname, $age) 
        {
           $this->firstname = $firstname;
           $this->lastname = $lastname;
           $this->age = $age;
       }
   }
   $teacher = new Person("boring", "12345", 12345);
   $student = new Person('hans', 'hansen', 24);
   $me = new Person('boring', '12345', 12345);
   echo $student->age;
  ?>
```

Comment: @sinaneker I think he means `$student->age` is empty, where he expects it to be 24.

Comment: @Mansfield a ok, but when I look on the code it should work

Comment: This looks fine.  Do you get an error, or just a blank page result?  Try looking at the page source in your browser to be 100% sure it's not hidden.  Also make sure there's no whitespace above your code.

Comment: Delete the `?>`. It doesn't make any sense in a pure php class

Comment: Your code is breaking the encapsulation. Please stop using `public` visibility where is no required. An object is **not** a glorified array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You misspelled 'construct', so nothing is being set.

Answer (score 1):

What is this ?

```
public function __costruct($firstname, $lastname, $age)
```

Check spelling `costruct` - it must be `construct`

Comment: check the spelling of `costruct` :-)

Answer (score 0):

It is a grammar error... you wrote `__contruct`

try just replacing this line: `public function __construct($firstname, $lastname, $age)`

good luck learning PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Spelling mistake exist

```
class Person 
{
    public $isAlive = true;
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;
    public $age;

    //spelling mistake exist
    public function __construct($firstname, $lastname, $age)
    {
        echo $firstname;

        $this->firstname = $firstname;
        $this->lastname = $lastname;
        $this->age = $age;

        echo 'i work';
    }

}
$teacher = new Person("boring", "12345", 12345);
$student = new Person('hans', 'hansen', 24);

//print_r($student);

if(is_object($student))
{
    echo $student->age;
}

$me = new Person('boring', '12345', 12345);
```